# Laravel eloquent is very slow when joining two models

Tags: laravel

There is a model `Invoice` which equals to a purchase basket and model `InvoiceItem` which stores items inside a specific *invoice*. The model invoice has `status` field, if its value is `2999` and someone has verified it, it is successful. I need to get invoice items which are sold. Here is codes:

```
class Invoice extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'payment_invoices';


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function scopeSuccessful($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 2999)->where('verified_at', '<>', null);
    }
}
```

and

```
class InvoiceItem extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'payment_invoice_items';


    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class, 'invoice_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class, 'vendor_id');
    }

    public function scopeNotDeleted($query)
    {
        return $query->where('deleted_at', null);
    }

    public function scopeSold($query)
    {
        return $query->notDeleted()->whereHas('invoice', function ($q) {
            $q->successful();
        });
    }
}
```

The following statement

> InvoiceItem::sold()->take(10)->get()

returns 10 sold items but it is very slow. it takes about 4 seconds to retrieve the information while the query

```
select *
from laravel.payment_invoice_items pii
join laravel.payment_invoices pi
    on pi.id = pii.invoice_id
    and pii.deleted_at isnull
    and pi.status=2999
    and pi.verified_at notnull
limit 10
```

takes about 800 milliseconds. Eloquent is very inefficient. Is there any solution to use the eloquent and get the same efficiency here?

Comment: `InvoiceItem::sold()->something` will get all invoice items in one query and get all their related sold items in a second query. This is more efficient than a join if you have a single or a few `InvoiceItem` models to retrieve but will not be efficient for all models. You could just use the join in this case or get the top 10 sold items `with` their respective invoice item if you want to use eloquent.

Comment: @apokryfos There are more than 1 million invoice and more than 5 million items

Comment: I missed the `sold` being a scope. I thought it was a relationship. The issue (I think) is that the JOIN / LIMIT combination does a query differently to the `whereHas` which translates to a `WHERE EXISTS (subquery)` in SQL. I think a better question here is how to get similar performance using a WHERE EXISTS as you would with a JOIN and that comes down to the database so I'm not really sure of the answer there